# Memory usage for arrays and vectors (64 bit)?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I'm storing large data and want to optimize memory. What I'm confused about is the following (compiling 64bit):

```
char a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
long long int b[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
vector<char> x = vector<char>(10,0);
vector<long long int> y = vector<long long int>(10,0);
cout << sizeof(a) <<" "<< sizeof(b)<< " " <<sizeof(x) <<" "<< sizeof(y)<< endl;
```

prints values 10 80 24 24.

1) Does char[10] actually only use 10 bytes? Shouldn't it use 80 bytes, since on a 64-bit compile the memory can be addressed for 64-bit blocks only?

2) Last two lines: why 24 (3 bytes?) Is it just that the structure of vector includes 24 bytes of data?

3) Does a vector of chars with 1000 elements use the same amount of memory as a vector of long long int with 1000 elements?

Comment: The first two are static arrays, memory is allocated on the stack. Vectors allocates memory on the heap and points to it. The size of the array is the size of the pointer plus some metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) a char is a single byte. Just because you are using a 64bit system *(which means that it can address a single byte using a 64bit address, and not that it can only read/write 64bits at a time)*. I think you may be confusing cache lines, and memory reads. Read a single byte from memory, and generally 64bytes will be fetched as a cache line. Nothing to do with accessing 1 byte or not.

2) sizeof returns the size *in bytes* and not *in bits*. std::vector is typically implemented as a structure of 3 pointers, one for the begin, end, and capacity:

```cpp
struct vector
{
  int* begin;
  int* end;
  int* capacity;
};
```

Since this is a 64bit system, your pointer values *(addresses)* will be 8bytes *(== 64bit)*. As a result, the sizeof 3xpointer values will be 24 *(3 * sizeof(void*))*.

Whatever data type you store in the vector, sizeof will always return 24 *(on a typical 64bit architecture)*

3) sizeof only calculates the raw size of a data structure. It doesn't account for the fact that a pointer value inside that struct has some extra dynamically allocated memory. To get the complete size, something like this would be needed:

```cpp
template<typename T>
size_t getUsedMemUsage(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
  size_t size_of_vector_struct = sizeof(std::vector<T>);
  size_t size_of_single_element = sizeof(T);
  return size_of_vector_struct + size_of_single_element * vec.size();
}
template<typename T>
size_t getFullMemUsage(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
  size_t size_of_vector_struct = sizeof(std::vector<T>);
  size_t size_of_single_element = sizeof(T);
  return size_of_vector_struct + size_of_single_element * vec.capacity();
}
```

Although that's not strictly true *(e.g. the OS may use a few extra bytes to align the memory allocation, and probably uses ~16bytes for keeping track of allocations)*.

So no, a vector of 1000 long long ints will use less memory than a vector of 1000 chars *(by an approximate factor of `sizeof(long long int) / sizeof(char)`)*

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to find out which [data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) is used and how much memory the various data types occupy.

1. The array data occupy a continuous memory area, while alignment as such does not occur, since all elements are of the same type. So `char[10]` will have a size of **10 * 1 = 10** bytes.
2. `std::vector` allocates memory on the heap, that is, it only stores a pointer to the allocated memory, but not the elements themselves. `std::vector` itself stores only a pointer to the allocated memory, the size of the allocated memory and the number of elements. The size of the pointer is 8 bytes, the size of other elements is usually also 8 bytes, so the `sizeof(std::vector<...>)`, regardless of the data type, will be **8 + 8 + 8 = 24** bytes.
3. I actually answered this question above. `sizeof(std::vector<...>)` is practically independent of the data type. The size of the allocated memory on the heap, in contrast, depends on the data type. `std::vector<long long>(1000)` consumes more memory than `std::vector<char>(1000)`.